# What is the DOS-counterpart of the bash command "ls -lad" on Unix?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, cmd.exe, ms-dos

What is the DOS-counterpart of the bash command `ls -lad` on Unix?

The "dir" command on Command Prompt (cmd.exe) on Windows is usually considered to be equivalent to the "ls" command of bash on Unix/Linux.  However, "dir" lacks the feature of the "-d" option of "ls".  The "-d" option treats directories like plain files, and prevents their child files and subdirectories from being displayed.

```
ls -lad ITEM
```

1. Basically, what I need is the existence and type of the given ITEM.
2. As for type, I need to know whether it is a directory, a regular file or a link.
3. If it is a directory, I do not want its child files nor subdirectories to be displayed.
4. If it is a link, I need to know the target.

Is there any DOS command (or even PowerShell command) with these features (1) through (4)?

```
dir ITEM /a
attrib ITEM
```

The "attrib" command on DOS also tells the existence of the given ITEM; and, if it is a directory, "attrib" refrains from displaying its child files and subdirectories.  However, "attrib" fails to tell whether it is a directory, a regular file or a link.

Answer (score 5):

#### What is the DOS-counterpart of the bash command `ls -lad`?

There is no direct equivalent. You can, of course, install Cygwin or the Windows Subsystem for Linux and run `ls -lad` directly.

You can also create a batch file that will do most of what you want. Below are some hints.

To check for the existence of a file:

```
if exist filename (
  echo filename exists
  )
```

To check if a file is a directory:

```
if exists filename\nul (
  echo directory
) else (
  echo file
)
```

To check if a file is a link:

```
dir /a:l filename | find "<SYMLINK>" >nul && echo file symbolic link
```

To check if a directory is a link:

```
dir /a:l filename | find "<SYMLINKD>" >nul && echo directory symbolic link
```

To get the target of a file link:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=[] tokens=2" %i in (`dir /a:l filename ^| find "<SYMLINK">`) do @echo %i
```

To get the target of a directory link:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=[] tokens=2" %i in (`dir /a:l filename* ^| find "<SYMLINKD>"`) do @echo %i
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) - Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.